# ProgrammingError: relation "django_session" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Got this error after changing my database from sqlite to postgresql. I've made all my settings changes:

Here's my settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        'NAME': "postr1",
        'USER': "zorgan",
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': "localhost",
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

as well as performing `makemigrations` and `migrations` which were all successful. So I'm able to succesfully start my local server:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 15, 2018 - 08:59:39
Django version 1.11.8, using settings 'draft1.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

however when I go to the site it returns this error:

```
ProgrammingError at /news/
relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: do you have `django.contrib.sessions` in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes I do have it

Comment: wierd. then please check you have `django_session` table in your database. in `python manage.py dbshell` and `\dt`

Comment: Hmm there is no `django_session` in my DB. Any idea why? There is `django_site` though.

Comment: django_site and django_session is totally different. I think sth wrong while you migrate. What happen when migrate again? `python manage.py migarte`

Comment: `Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, comment, contenttypes, django_celery_beat, djstripe, draft1, polls, post, profiles, sessions, sites, socialaccount
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
`

Comment: can you check `python manage.py showmigrations` with `sessions`?

Comment: that returns: `sessions
 [X] 0001_initial`

Comment: ok. then lets try fake migrate. I will upload answer

Comment: I got this same error. I noticed that if I have to use a database (even in production) I must run `python3 manage.py migrate`  this issue affected my production for long. I had to solve the issue by connecting to my production database and then running `python3 manage.py migrate`.    
 Just putting this out here in case someone runs into the same issue

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try `fake migrate` to zero.

Your migration history shows that `sessions` table was already made, but you don't have real table.

so following below

```
python manage.py migrate --fake sessions zero
# then your sessions migrate will be
python manage.py showmigrations
sessions
 [ ] 0001_initial
# then migrate with --fake-initial again
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm using django-v-3**

**Here is the answer how to solve this issue?**

> **1. python manage.py migrate --fake**
>  
>   **2. python manage.py migrate --fake-initial**
>  
>   **3. Then write python manage.py runserver**

**Enjoy**

**If facing issue use python manage.py help. I hope that you will get the solution.**

Answer (score 0):

Since you were using sqlite and changed to Postgres, your user and password no longer work and you got that error. Depending on what is your docker-compose.yml file you can do a migrate command:
docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate
and than create a new superuser:
docker-compose exec web python manage.py createsuperuser
Now your app should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a solution for an additional possible way this failure could occur.

I was struggling with the session tables not being created.

I tried the fake migration reset strategy suggested by @seuling and still was not getting the tables created.

It turns out that the enterprise installation I am working on has a highly sharded database, and the session tables are not in the same database as the default database.

So to get this to work, I performed the above fake migration steps, **and also had to specify the database**: `--database <session_db>`

e.g.

`manage.py migrate --database session`