# heroku deployment, relation "django_session" does not exist

Tags: python, django, database, heroku, deployment

I've build a simple browser game on Python+Django, which is using session/cookies to track the score. The game it self doesn't have any database. When I'm deploying to heroku, I got this type of error

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_sessio...
                               ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://lesgogo.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_sessio...
                               ^
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 86
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python38.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 13 Jun 2020 04:00:23 +0000
```

what I've tried:

- deployed successfully to heroku without views.py (the logic part with session in that file), static files like img and css were loaded/showed properly
- I was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346326/programmingerror-relation-django-session-does-not-exist) and tried that:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake sessions zero
# then your sessions migrate will be
python manage.py showmigrations
sessions
 [ ] 0001_initial
# then migrate with --fake-initial again
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

added, and pushed back to heroku, didn't worked.

- my settings.py file is pretty much default, so all middlewares are there, I just added my app name

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

the versions i'm using

```
python-3.8.3
asgiref==3.2.7
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.7
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
psycopg2==2.8.5
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
whitenoise==5.1.0
```

PS: it's my first post. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

After following the advice in this link [ProgrammingError: relation "django_session" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346326/programmingerror-relation-django-session-does-not-exist) (it is the link you mention above), I then did

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations sessions
heroku run python manage.py migrate sessions
```

Comment: Don't run `makemigrations` on Heroku. By the time the code gets deployed there should be no model changes that would generate new migrations. Run that _locally_ and commit the migrations. `migrate` should be run in both places, though. That applies the migrations.